# Image of this set under $\cos z$

Tags: complex-analysis

Given $S:= \{z\in \mathbb{C}:0<\Re(z)<\frac{\pi}{2},\Im(z) > 0\}.$

Find the image of $S$ under $w = \cos z$.

This is what I did:

$z:= x+iy \implies w = \cos x \cosh y - i \sin x \sinh y = u+iv$ since  $w:= u+iv$.

So we have, for fixed $y$,
$$\frac{u}{\cosh y} = \cos x \\ \frac{v}{\sinh y} = -\sin x$$
and so
$$\frac{u^2}{\cosh ^2 y ^2} + \frac{v^2}{\sinh ^2 y } = 1$$
for $u>0$ and $v<0$.
However, this doesn't tell me much I think, it just says that for fixed $y$, I get an ellipse. If I change $y$ (infinitely), it'd be infinite ellipses, which would seem to fill almost all of the $u-v$ plane (in the fourth quadrant). Similarly, I could show that for fixed $x$, it would form a hyperbola.

Is this correct and is there a better way to approach this?
Is there software online where I can visualise images of sets under complex functions?

Comment: I think $u>0$ and $v<0$ says the Image of $S$ is $\{(u,v):u>0,\,v<0\}$.

Comment: I thought it just means that the *possible* values of $u$ are $u>0$ and *possible* values of $v$ are $v<0$, and the ellipse/hyperbola equations would further reduce the possible values

Comment: Here is java based tool helps you find the graph better http://www.jimrolf.com/java/complexTool/complexTool.html

Comment: Playing around with it, if I fixed $x$-line (which maps to a hyperbola below the x-axis),and drew horizontal lines starting on the y-axis towards the fixed $x$ line, the resulting ellipses would always stop when it touched the hyperbolae. Wondering why this is true...

Comment: So the image is the part above the negative hyperbola branch, and under the x-axis it seems..